# Transparent background on a activity that uses actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles

Does anyone know how can I make the activity background transparent and show the actionbar(not transparent) at the same time?

I've tried this

```
    <style name="Theme.PureTransparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

but I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.activities.SearchTitleStrip}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myapp.activities.SearchTitleStrip.setActionbarSearch(SearchTitleStrip.java:80)
            at com.myapp.activities.SearchTitleStrip.onCreate(SearchTitleStrip.java:72)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
```

Line 80 in SearchTitleStrip class is this code:
`actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`

Comment: i'm not sure ut i think if you set a transparent background in the main element of the activity layout to transparent it should work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set

```
android:background="#AARRGGBB"
```

in the activity xml, where AA is the alpha value(for transparency level), followed by red green and blue.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my issue by adding this in to styles.xml(I've used actionbar Sherlock):

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarTransparentBackground" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```